# JavaFX allow user only to edit certain areas of text

Tags: java, xml, javafx

I'm designing a custom XML view with javafx.
Imagine the following XML.

```
<CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
```

Now I want the user to be able to edit the title, the artist etc. without him being able to change the rest of the XML.
Note that my goal is to achieve this with XML style and dont present the user with a input, dialog.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: what JavaFX component are you using to present you xml?

Comment: I use a TextArea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could a layout for the xml on your own that uses `Text` nodes for the start/end tags and `TextField`s for the text content:

```
String input = "<CD>\n"
        + "    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>\n"
        + "    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>\n"
        + "    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>\n"
        + "    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>\n"
        + "    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>\n"
        + "    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>\n"
        + "</CD>";
XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, Boolean.TRUE);
XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()));

List<List<Node>> currentChildren = new ArrayList<>();
currentChildren.add(new ArrayList<>(1));
String text = null;
int depth = 0;
final Insets insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 20);
boolean hasChildren = false;

while (reader.hasNext()) {
    switch (reader.next()) {
        case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
            depth++;
            hasChildren = false;
            currentChildren.add(new ArrayList<>());
            break;
        case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
            text = reader.getText();
            break;
        case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
            String suffix = reader.getName().getLocalPart() + ">";
            if (hasChildren) {
                // element group
                VBox vbox = new VBox(new Text("<" + suffix));
                for (Node n : currentChildren.get(depth)) {
                    VBox.setMargin(n, insets);
                }
                vbox.getChildren().addAll(currentChildren.get(depth));
                vbox.getChildren().add(new Text("</" + suffix));
                currentChildren.get(depth - 1).add(vbox);
            } else {
                // text element
                TextField textField = new TextField(text);
                textField.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
                textField.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

                // keep size of TextField large enough to contain all the text
                ChangeListener<String> listener = new ChangeListener<String>() {

                    private final Text measureElement = new Text();

                    {
                        measureElement.setFont(Font.font("monospaced"));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                        measureElement.setText(newValue);
                        textField.setPrefWidth(measureElement.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() + 2);
                    }

                };
                listener.changed(null, null, text);
                textField.textProperty().addListener(listener);
                HBox hbox = new HBox(new Text('<' + suffix), textField, new Text("</" + suffix));
                currentChildren.get(depth - 1).add(hbox);
                hasChildren = true;
                text = null;
            }
            currentChildren.remove(depth);
            depth--;
            break;
    }
}

VBox root = (VBox) currentChildren.get(0).get(0);
root.getStyleClass().add("xml-editor");
```

#### CSS Stylesheet

```css
.xml-editor .text-field,
.xml-editor .text-field:focused {
    /* remove TextField border & background */
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-control-inner-background: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-box-border: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-font-family: 'monospaced';
}

.xml-editor Text {
    -fx-font-family: 'monospaced';
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly. Am I allowed to use this in my code? Under which license is your code? =)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`TextFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) with a regex-filter to ensure the format:

This is just a small example: (You should adapt the regex to your needs)

```
TextArea ta = new TextArea();

ta.setText("<CD>\n    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>\n    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>\n    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>\n    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>\n    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>\n    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>\n</CD>");

UnaryOperator<Change> filter = c -> {
    if(c.getControlNewText().matches("<CD>\\n    <TITLE>.*</TITLE>\\n    <ARTIST>.*</ARTIST>\\n    <COUNTRY>.*</COUNTRY>\\n    <COMPANY>.*</COMPANY>\\n    <PRICE>[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*</PRICE>\\n    <YEAR>[0-9]{0,4}</YEAR>\\n</CD>")) {
        return c;
    }
    // The new input doesn't match the regex and gets discarded
    return null;
};

ta.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(filter));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using the [TextFlow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) component.

It works by passing objects to your `TextFlow` such as `TextField`, `Text` etc.

You can add custom styling to each of these objects.

Now, your XML titles could be `Text` objects for example and your values `TextField` ones.

Then, you could choose whether a `TextField` object you are adding to the `TextFlow` is editable or not. For example:

```
Text field = new Text("one");
TextField value = new TextField("two");
value.setPrefWidth(value.getText().length()*12); // customize if needed
value.setStyle("-fx-fill: RED;-fx-font-weight:normal;"); // adding css
value.setEditable(false); // this field cannot be edited
textFlow.getChildren().addAll(field,value);
```